# Err:4 downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

I have Kubuntu 18.04.01 installed on my PC.  I'm a computer tech, but I have extremely limited knowledge of Linux.  Everything is running fine, but I can no longer update the system.

`sudo` command doesn't work in the terminal and the Software Center fails to update.  I am entering the correct password, but the system fails to update.  The Software Center does successfully find the package to update.  I get an error message from the Software Center, but it is a light grey background with dark grey text. I'm unable to read it before it shuts off.

Below is the text from the terminal after the root login fails.

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for glen: 
Hit:1 repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                
Get:3 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                                               
Get:4 downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease [3,408 B]                                                       
Ign:5 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                              
Hit:6 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                         
Hit:7 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                      
Hit:8 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                
Err:4 downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease                           
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 97203C7B3ADCA79D
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 97203C7B3ADCA79D
E: The repository 'downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: **1:** What exactly do you mean by "Below is the text from the terminal after the root login fails." If the login failed how could you access anything? **2:** When posting terminal output, please include the actual command including the terminal prompts at the beginning and after the command has completed, whether successful or not. **3:** Use this site's [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) especially when posting code.

Comment: You most likely need to import the signing key from plex.tv.

Comment: `sudo` is working fine - the error is from APT

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your password, all works. You have problem with the `plex.tv` repository.

Try removing that PPA, for example by unchecking it in **Software Sources** in **Software and Updates**. You can try adding it again if you need it.